# Remove lines in file NOT containing characters in whitelist

Tags: bash, unix, sed

How do I remove all lines in file containing characters NOT in my whitelist?

Whitelisted characters:

```
A-Z a-z {}!@$%&().,;'"
```

Input:

```
the socialist government of josé sócrates
all of that is to be commended.
allow me a final comment {please}
watch tom & jerry
```

Output:

```
all of that is to be commended.
allow me a final comment {please}
watch tom & jerry
```

I tried `sed '/[A-Za-z]{}!@$%&().,;'"/,$d' input` but it doesn't match per character.. any help?

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? Also, your regex seems malformed. You need to have the curly braces and all the other whitelisted characters in the square brackets along with the alphabetic character tokens.

Comment: Python could be a good way to handle the regexes

Comment: Yes, but so would any number of tools, including Ruby, PHP, C# etc. etc. etc. Usually you tag the question with the language your question/code pertains to.

Comment: I think you mean `remove all lines in file NOT containing characters in my whitelist`. If I am right, could you confirm or even better - edit your question - please?

Comment: @Asad I'm learning python and been told python is best to handle things like these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the weirder tricks in bash is to match a double-negative. Here, we print only lines that do *not* contain any characters *not* in our list:

```
pat='A-Z a-z{}!@$%&().,;"'"'"
while read -r; do
  if [[ $REPLY != *[^$pat]* ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
  fi
done
```

This is more commonly done when trying to tell if a value is purely numeric (`$var != *[^0-9]*`), but it works here as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a sequence of unique characters by making a `set` from the line. Then it is easy to compare to your whitelist:

```
from string import ascii_letters

WHITELIST = ascii_letters + ''' {}!@$%&().,;'"'''

with open('myfile.txt') as f, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as f2:
    ok_lines = [line for line in f if set(line.strip()) <= set(WHITELIST)
    f2.writelines(ok_lines)
```

The reason we make a new file is you can't simply remove a line. We have to take the lines we want and then re-write these lines.

Comment: space is missing in whitelist, but apart from that, very nice use of set

Answer (score 1):

As you are using from unix, try using Perl oneliner:

```
cat input.txt | perl -ne 'print for /^([A-Za-z{}!@$%&().,;\'"\s]+)$/g;'
```

Redirect the output to any other file using `> output.txt`

Alternately you can also try to take backup of your current file and then modify automatically:

```
perl -i.bak -ne "print for /^([A-Za-z{}!@$%&().,;'\"\s]+)$/g;" input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Python solution:

```
import string

fname = 'myfile.txt'
whitelist = string.ascii_letters + """{}!@$%&(),;'". """
```

(break to reset highliter)

```
with open(fname) as f:
    for line in f:
        if all((ch in whitelist) for ch in line.strip()):
            print line.rstrip('\n')
# this prints relevant lines to stdout
```

or as oneliner:

```
print '\n'.join(line for line in txt.splitlines() 
                if all((ch in whitelist) for ch in line ))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new file with lines that only have characters in whitelist - Python:

```
whitelist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
             'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
             's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A',
             'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
             'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
             'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' ', '{',
             '}', '!', '@', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '.',
             ',', ';', '"', "'"]

with open('input.txt', 'r') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if not all(c in whitelist for c in line.strip()):
            continue
        outfile.write(line)
```